# Flows issue when deployed to packaging dev org

Tags: visual-flows, namespace

I have a set of flows that I want to include in a managed package. The flows were built in a dev/scratch org with no namespace. After deploying (sfdx) to the packaging org with a namespace, I get an error when I try to run any of the flows, all of which start by waiting for a platform event.

> Error element Intake_Member_Fires (WaitInfo). No match for type :
>   "null" cannot get corresponding flow type

The error occurs on the very first step, which is waiting for a platform event, which was deployed but now has the namespace prefix.

---

Everything I'm reading [here in the docs](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/212/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.pdf) says Flows should adapt to the namespace, so maybe this isn't a namespace issue. Not sure what else to try...

---

UPDATE: I was misguided to suspect the namespace, that's not the issue. For some reason, when deployed to the packaging Org, the Wait step in the Flow is losing its Event Conditions and Variable Assignments tied to the Platform Event. I was able to add them back in on the Packaging Org, but I won't be able to do that after it's packaged and distributed. I hope the same thing doesn't happen when I deploy through the package. I'll update when I'm able to test it.

---

UPDATE: When I fixed the flows on the packaging org and created the managed package, the flows installed and run correctly on the test Enterprise org.